# Installing Python on CentOS

Tags: python, python-2.7, makefile

I have CentOS 6.5. I needed to install python 2.7.6 on this computer with altinstall. so I downloaded python from the following link:

```
http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.6/Python-2.7.6.tar.xz
```

untar-ed the file.then used the following command

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-unicode=ucs4 --enable-shared LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib"
```

after I use "make" and the following error apeared

```
File "/home/Python-2.7.6/Lib/site.py", line 548, in <module>
main()
File "/home/Python-2.7.6/Lib/site.py", line 530, in main
known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
File "/home/Python-2.7.6/Lib/site.py", line 266, in addusersitepackages
user_site = getusersitepackages()
File "/home/Python-2.7.6/Lib/site.py", line 241, in getusersitepackages
user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
File "/home/Python-2.7.6/Lib/site.py", line 231, in getuserbase
USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
File "/home/Python-2.7.6/Lib/sysconfig.py", line 516, in get_config_var
return get_config_vars().get(name)
File "/home/Python-2.7.6/Lib/sysconfig.py", line 468, in get_config_vars
_init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
File "/home/Python-2.7.6/Lib/sysconfig.py", line 352, in _init_posix
from _sysconfigdata import build_time_vars
ImportError: No module named _sysconfigdata
make: *** [sharedmods] Error 1
```

how can I fix this ?